Inject a script in iframe
I'm attempting to inject a script into a page loaded within an iframe (originating from a different domain). I'm encountering the same-origin policy restriction. I've endeavored to circumvent this by launching Chrome with the "--disable-web-security" flag, but it seems to have lost its efficacy. Extensions have proven equally ineffective. Is there a viable workaround for Chrome, or perhaps an alternative browser that dispenses with web security entirely? It's important to note that I'm not interested in employing the postMessage solution, as I'm not intending to add any scripts to the other website.

No, this is not possible, and postMessage() won't work for you as you don't have access to update the domain showing content in the iframe.

The potential for abuse with something like this seems pretty high.  This sounds like the kind of thing for which you'd need to write a browser extension, or even a custom fork of the browser itself.

You have to specify the --user-data-dir argument too, as a security limitation from Chromium itself. Do keep in mind that you should not use this as your daily browser, as the security implications of disabling CORS are big, exposing you to XSS attacks among others.
--disable-web-security --user-data-dir "[folder of your choosing]"

Extensions can also inject scripts into iframes, by specifying "all_frames" within the manifest. This is a much better solution than disabling CORS. This question has already been answered here too.

Concerning --user-data-dir , I did that but it did not work.. Thanks for your answer
